# Error relation does not exist SQL WITH on POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I get ERROR: relation "case_avg" does not exist in my sql request

```
    with case_avg AS
                (select
                               avg(vv.total_vcpu) as avgvcpu,
                               avg(vv.total_vram) as avgvram,
                               avg(vv.total_hdd) as avghdd,
                               pod,
                               report_date
                from common.vmware_vm vv
                group by pod,report_date)

select
    (ca.avgvcpu-v.total_vcpu) as vcpu,
    (ca.avgvram-v.total_vram) as vram,
    (ca.avghdd-v.total_hdd) as hdd,
    Concat(lower(v.vdc),lower(v.org)) as org_vdc
from
    common.vmware_vm v
inner join case_avg  ca on
    ca.pod = v.pod and ca.report_date = v.report_date 
group by org_vdc
```

How i can resolve this?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `group by` in the final query does not seem to make sense. You are not aggregating anything in that SELECT.

Comment: not only that but its grouping by a column alias, can that even work? No columns are aggregated so this *shouldn't* compile

Comment: @Stu: Postgres allows grouping by a column alias. So from a syntax point of view, that's OK

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  Instead I get `column "ca.avgvcpu" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`